# .mov files getting stored as text in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to store a .mov file in Firebase storage in my React Native app. 
I convert the file to a blob and upload it to Firebase. The file is being stored in Firebase with the type of `video/mov` so everything seems cool.

[image]

However, when I try and download the file, it is being downloaded as a text file and now looking at it, it looks like it's being stored as a text file.

[image]

Any thoughts on why this is happening? The video I record on my phone is being saved to the disk w/ the .mov extension btw.

Here is the relevant code

```
this.camera.capture({mode: Camera.constants.CaptureMode.video})
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data)
      const video = data.path;
      this.props.dispatch(saveVideoPath(video));
      let rnfbURI = RNFetchBlob.wrap(video);
      Blob
        .build(rnfbURI, { type : 'video/mov'})
        .then((blob) => {
          console.log(blob);
          storageRef.child('video/' + '12345').put(blob, { contentType : 'video/mov' })
            .then((snapshot) => {
              const downloadURL = snapshot.downloadURL
              this.props.dispatch(saveVideoDownloadURL(downloadURL));
              console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
            }).catch(error => console.log(error));
        })
    })
```

Comment: Have you tried to open the file with an other app, with a video app?

Comment: @AlexMamo I download it via the firebase downloadURL but it downloads as a text file so I can't open it w/ a video app. I'd assume it would download with the .mov extension then I'd use Quicktime or something

Comment: You can open any file in any program, not that it will look right, but still, you can open it. If you just opened your movie player and use the open command in there and point to the file, does it load the video properly?

Comment: I bet if you upload the file with the name that ends in ".mov", that would clue  the browser into saving the file with the same name, and launching it would automatically use a video player instead of a text viewer.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn No. Says it can't open files in the "data" format.

Comment: @DougStevenson Not sure I follow? I am specifying what to save the file as `storageRef.child('video/' + '12345').put(blob, { contentType : 'video/mov' })`

Comment: You're naming the file "12345".  Try "12345.mov" instead.

Comment: @DougStevenson Ahh. Ok. I'll give that a shot. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are trying to open the saved video file with a `file viewer` in stead of a `video player`, that's why you see those symbols. To solve this, change the app with which you are opening the movie files and try to choose `Quicktime` . As i see in your screenshot, the type of your file is `video/mov`. So it's a video file and not a text file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: When I try that, it says the document could not be opened. QuickTime Player cannot open files in the "data" format.

Comment: Are you sure that your file has the `.mov` extension? If not, please upload the file with the same name and make sure the file has the correct `.mov` extension. Try this example: name your file: `movie.mov` Does it work?

Comment: Yeah. Thanks! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. The solution was to set the `contentDisposition` property to an empty string when the file extension was '.mov'.

So my metadata looked something like this:

```
var metadata = {
             contentType: 'video/quicktime',
             name: 'videoName.mov',
             contentDisposition: ''
};
```

Hope this helps.