# How to upload a video to firebase firestore in React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Im currently able to upload an image to firebase firestore by storing it in a blob and upload it to firestore. How would i do the same but for a video instead, would I also put it in a blob? Below is the code I use to upload an image.

```
openLibrary = async () => {
 const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL)
 if (status === 'granted') {
 const image = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({allowsEditing: true})
 if(!image.cancelled){
 const url = await this.props.uploadPhoto(image)
 this.props.updatePhoto(url)
      }
    }
  }
export const uploadPhoto = (image) => {
 return async (dispatch) => {
 try {
 console.log("in upload photo")
 const resize = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(image.uri, [], { format: 'jpeg', compress: 0.1 })
 const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
 xhr.onload = () => resolve(xhr.response)
 xhr.responseType = 'blob'
 xhr.open('GET', resize.uri, true)
 xhr.send(null)
      });
 const uploadTask = await firebase.storage().ref().child(uuid.v4()).put(blob)
 const downloadURL = await uploadTask.ref.getDownloadURL()
 return downloadURL
    } catch(e) {
 console.log("in upload photo error")
 console.error(e)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: All uploads and downloads to and from Cloud Storage work the same way - file types do no receive special treatment.  They are just sequences of bytes.

Comment: Also note: you're not uploading the video to Cloud Firestore (a document database), but are uploading it to Cloud Storage (a blog storage solution) and then storing a URL to the video in the database.

Comment: Between Doug's and my comment, the question seems to boil down to : https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+react+native+pick+or+record

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I managed to upload it however when I download the file it downloads as text format how do I get it in video format?

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to download the file?

Perhaps when you upload the video you aren't setting the file type/extension when you upload or download (mp4, mov, etc.).

Try adding the file extension desired, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44572667/mov-files-getting-stored-as-text-in-firebase) for an example.